# Do "neocons" and "neoliberals" have the same foreign policy views?

Tags: conservatism, liberalism, george-w-bush

I've heard that Bush can be described as a "neocon" and Clinton as a "neolib."

Given that

- **the neocons originally came from the political left**
- **neoliberals are more concerned with domestic economic policy rather than foreign policy**

is it accurate to say that in actuality "neocons" and "neoliberals" have the same foreign policy views?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more how you arrived at the conclusion that similar foreign policy goals follow from your two  bullet points? Or do you have specific shared goals in mind?

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what you mean by "neocon" and neoliberal"

Comment: You have the following statement/assumption: “Given that
the neocons originally came from the political left” Please provide a source and justification for this. I don’t regard the statement as evident. Is it true in the last 20 years?

Comment: I should have said “in the last 30 years“ to cover the relevant administrations, but I think the assertion needs historical context, and historical context is contestable.

Comment: @corporal "neocons" coming from the political left is just the etymology of the word, I don't think the author needs to define words when they are using them as they are used.  Neo=new.  Cons=conservatives.  The words was created for pro-war formerly-left-wing political actors.  At the time the word was created, the pro-war standing was considered a right-wing position.  Some of this has shifted, of course.

Comment: @Hulk I think they are asking *if* they have similar foreign policy goals.  You can ask authors to justify premises of their questions, but I don't see any point in asking authors to justify the inquiry parts of their questions.

Comment: There is the concept of the "blob" which basically encapsulates what you are talking about: https://www.vox.com/22153765/joe-biden-foreign-policy-team-revenge-blob .  A good example was how Biden was attacked from both the mainstream left (CNN, MSNBC) and right (fox et al) for Afghanistan.

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/2021/09/16/us/politics/blob-afghanistan-withdrawal-biden.amp.html

Comment: @corporal - The original neoconservatives certainly came from disillusioned members of left-wing movements, as a quick survey of the accompanying Wikipedia article can confirm. The current neoconservatives, on the other hand, are their intellectual heirs, and never were left-wing or liberal.

Comment: The short answer is "no". Also, Neocons came mostly from the political right.